# Can someone explain this Theorem about the probability of correction of a codeword during standard array decoding to me?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, coding-theory

Hello I'm working on a presentation about linear codes and i dont really understand this theorem. Can someone give more detail on it please? The theorem is from a book called "A first course in coding theory" by Raymond Hill.
picture from the book: [Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5fII.png)

Theorem:
Let $C$ be a binary $[n,k]-Code$ and for $i=0,...,n$ let $\alpha_i$ be the number of coset-leaders of weight $i$.Then the probability $P_{corr}(C)$ that a received vector decoded by means of a standard array is the codeword that was sent is given by:
$$P_{corr} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *specific* error pattern with weight $i$ occurs with the probability
$$
q_i:=p^i (1-p)^{n-i}.
$$
In syndrome decoding any error pattern in a coset is "corrected" as if the error pattern is actually the coset leader (coset leader is added modulo 2 to the received word). The decoding is correct if and only if the error pattern is actually the coset leader.

Therefore the only corrected error patterns are the collections of coset leaders.

Since the event "decoding is successful" is a disjoint union of the events, "the error pattern is a specific coset leader", and there are $\alpha_i$ coset leaders with weight $i,$ the claim follows by summing the probabilities of these disjoint events.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a whole lot of sense. I was just so confused since the book gave absolutely no explanation what so ever. Thanks!!!

Comment: you're welcome. you can upvote and accept the answer since you like it.

Comment: For standard-arrray decoding, _all_ decodings are successful, by definition. It is only in bounded-distance decoding and the like that the decoder might not be able to decode at all; an event that is called decoder _failure_. In this latter case, a successful decoding might result in a correct codeword, or an incorrect codeword and so (successful decoding) is the disjoint union of (correct decoding) and (erroneous decoding) and we have three probabilities to contend with, P(correct decoding), P(decoder error), and P(decoder failure).